# can't remove breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've a solid break point in Visual Studio 2008 that I can't remove. I can add other break points. Some removed but some don't.

The error is "can't insert breakpoint"

How can this be fixed?

---

This is very weird. I added a new line above the lines that I couldn't removed and was able to remove them.

Anyone who adds more information on this will get credit.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

This would happen when the breakpoint gets out of sync from the parse tree.

Go to the Breakpoints pane (Debug, Windows, Breakpoints) and delete it from there.

Comment: To clarify, SLaks says, "delete it ..."; don't just uncheck it. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes the solution *.suo file can become corrupt. This is where the breakpoints are stored. You can workaround the issue by deleting the suo file.

Comment: Make sure to close visual studio before you delete the .suo file otherwise it'll recreate it with the same bug once you do close it.

Answer (score 12):

The shortcut command Control+Shift+F9 deletes all breakpoints.