# Visual Studio 2015 Breakpoint does not remove while debugging

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

When I try to delete a breakpoint while debugging my ASP.NET app, it returns as soon as I stop the debugger.  I don't know if this is a bug or an intended feature.  If it is an intended feature, how do I turn it off?

If it is a bug, I can replicate it by:
1. Put a breakpoint in my code
2. Run the code in debug mode (F5)
3. When the code breaks at my breakpoint, press F9 to remove the break point.  Then press F5 to continue.
4. Stop program execution (either by the stop button or closing the browser).
5. Breakpoint re-appears.

Note: if I go into the Breakpoints window and find the line with the breakpoint on it and delete it from there, it stays away.  It just doesn't delete when I hit F9 while in break mode.

Comment: This bug has been around for a long time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983918/visual-studio-refuses-to-forget-breakpoints

Comment: When you hit the breakpoint, can you look at the Breakpoints Window and either post a screenshot or describe the breakpoint there. Is it a single breakpoint? Does it have children?

Comment: It is a single breakpoint.  No children.