# Why are Breakpoints removed in Visual Studio after restarting a VM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I have placed couple of breakpoints in Visual studio to debug my application but if I start my VM then all breakpoints are removed. How can I restore my breakpoints points?

They seem to have gone:

Expected : Breakpoints should persist  across VM restarts

Comment: What is a debug point? Do you mean breakpoint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983918/visual-studio-refuses-to-forget-breakpoints may be worth reading.

Comment: What role is the VM playing?  Is VS running on the VM?

Comment: Yes, Debug point is break point

Comment: Yes, VS running on VM